# Communicating events from a service to a controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope

I have an audio element in my service that has a "ended" event listener. I'm trying to communicate that message to an angular controller.

Currently I have this in my service:

```
Audio.addEventListener "ended", (->
      $rootScope.$broadcast("audioEnded")
    ), false
```

And in my controller I have:

```
$scope.$on "audioEnded", ->
      console.log("ended scope")
```

This works but I'm wondering if there is a better way to communicate from a service to a controller without using $rootScope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to achieve what you want is to implement event aggregator as a service. You could use it in any directive, controller or config function by simple dependency injection.

```
app.service 'vent', ->
    handlers: []
    on: (eventName, handler) ->
       #register handler
    emit: (eventName, args...) ->
       #iterate events and call registered handlers
```

use example:

```
app.controller 'Ctrl', (vent) ->
    vent.on 'eventname', ->
        #...
    vent.emit 'eventname'
```

Comment: It feels a bit odd that this infrastructure is not part of angular core. $rootScope works fine for controllers, but not much else.